# If class true add url to iframe and work through a list of url's then repeat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, if-statement, src

I am wondering how to go about adding different url's to an iframe if an element has the `class="show"` so the 1st time the element class is "show" it will load the url:
about.html

the second time the **same** element has the class "show" it will open 
work.html

and then the 3d time the same element has the class "show" it will open
contact.html

etc etc

but on the last class that is "show" that opens contact.html how would I then start it again so the 4th time the class equals "show" it opens about.html again and the 5th time the class is "show" it opens work.html etc etc ?

Any idea's thanks!
I hope this makes sense also.

edit the class show changes between show and hidden depending on if the video modal is open or not so the first time the class is show it should display for example about.html and then for the 2nd time the class is show it should be work.html and the 3rd contact etc hope that makes better sense

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: since you have code that's setting the class to "show", maybe that's where you should keep track of the number of times it's been run and set the iframe's source there?

Comment: I'm currently playing with adding 1 to a var each time the class changes to "show" it will add 1 to a var I'm looking at then setting the var back to 1 once it reaches the last 'page' struggling a little though it's the best i've come up with so far then I'll use if statements so if the var is 3 it will attr contact.html to the ifame and if it's 1 it will attr about.html to the iframe src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the data api jquery provides instead of using a class,
here is a link to the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/data/

for example:

```
//Default value
$('#foo').data('num', 1);

//Go to next page event
$("#GoToNextPage").on("click", function(){
 NextUrl();
});  

function NextUrl(){
    var elem = $('#foo');
    var number = elem.data('num');
    if(number === 2){
      elem.src = 'URL.html'
    }
}
```